# how use netcat to test socks5 server?

Tags: tcp, proxy, netcat, socks

In [rfc1928](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt), first, client must send a message to server:

```
           client send to server:

           +----+----------+----------+
           |VER | NMETHODS | METHODS  |
           +----+----------+----------+
           | 1  |    1     | 1 to 255 |
           +----+----------+----------+
```

and then server should return message following :

```
                 +----+--------+
                 |VER | METHOD |
                 +----+--------+
                 | 1  |   1    |
                 +----+--------+
```

So i am using command line to test:

```
$ echo -e '0x01''0x01''0x01' | nc test.com 30
```

this command should return to me

```
0x01 0x01
```

But return me nothing with empty blank

Answer (score 1):

The decimal numbers appearing in packet-format diagrams represent the length of the corresponding field, in octets, not the value you are supposed to use.

The version field for a socks5 proxy should be `0x05`. The values of NMETHODS and METHODS depend on which methods you want to check.

Lastly, the raw output of the response message consists of non-printable characters, so you normally wouldn't be able to see it even if it was there, and apparently you need to end the input of netcat with a CR-LF or wait forever so it actually sends the message.

So in summary, to check for method `0x00` (no authentication), you could do something like

```
printf "\x05\x01\x00\r\n" | nc test.com 30 | hd
```

and get

```
00000000  05 00                                             |..|
00000002
```

on success.

Comment: and what would it tell me if that command just hangs and never finishes?

Comment: probably the TCP connection could not be established, or the SOCKS server is not answering your message, try putting nc in verbose mode with `-v` and setting a timeout with `-w <SECONDS>`